# Why would I choose Libav over FFmpeg, or is there even a difference?

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

From what I've seen it looks to me like Libav's `avconv` is thought to become a successor of `ffmpeg` — is that correct?

If that's true, why is that so? What exactly is libav doing better and why would I want to choose it over ffmpeg?

I came to this "issue" while installing Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS in a VM and when I've installed ffmpeg it came up with a message telling mit ffmpeg is deprecated and I first thought "wtf?".

If I use `avconv`Will I be able to migrate my scripts depending on ffmpeg more or less easy to libav? I'm mostly using it for writing meta data and doing audio conversion (wav, flac, vorbis, mp3, aac).

Answer (score 128, accepted):

## Libav is dead

[Last commit](https://git.libav.org/?p=libav.git) was on 2019-08-21. Use FFmpeg.

Some Libav developers are now participating again in FFmpeg. This is partly due to Jean-Baptiste Kempf (VideoLAN president) recently spearheading the [re-organization of the community](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2019-November/253153.html). A 5-person Technical Resolution Committee has been created with (former) Libav members holding two seats and Libav developers are welcome to join the General Assembly–a voting board for decision making. [Discussions and meetings](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2019-December/254105.html) are still on-going, but after 8 years since the fork this may mark the beginning of a re-integration.

---

## Original answer:

First of all see [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017). Much of the confusion is the result of:

1. Users not differentiating between the projects, FFmpeg and libav, and their respective command-line tools, `ffmpeg` and `avconv`.
2. The poorly worded message(s) users get when they try to use libav's `ffmpeg`.

#### FFmpeg vs `ffmpeg` and libav vs `avconv`

- FFmpeg is the project name. `ffmpeg` is the name of their command line tool.
- libav is the project name. `avconv` is the name of their command line tool. For a short time libav also had a `ffmpeg`.

Users often think "project" when "tool" is being discussed which leads to...

#### A poorly worded message

So, as we learned from the [Who can tell me...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017) link, when libav forked from FFmpeg they also temporarily supplied their version of `ffmpeg`. As a member of libav, the ffmpeg maintainer in Debian and Ubuntu then decided to switch the distro to use libav. From the perspective of libav this was their best move: to force a large user community to use the fork.

Ubuntu switched during the transitional period when libav supplied both their version of `ffmpeg` and their renamed tool `avconv`. When users attempted to use libav's `ffmpeg` they got the following message:

```
This program is not developed anymore and is only provided for compatibility.  
Use avconv instead (see Changelog for the list of incompatible changes).
```

In this case the "ffmpeg" mentioned in the message was libav's temporary version which was later removed (as was the message). Remember the difference between FFmpeg and `ffmpeg`? Of course this message thoroughly confused many users who understandably did not make the distinction between project and tool; especially Ubuntu users who were not aware that their distro did a switcharoo or users who never heard of libav. I don't know if libav intended users to think this, but they probably enjoyed this side-effect.

Some Ubuntu users thought the message was too misleading and it was later changed to:

```
***THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED***
This program is not developed anymore and is only provided for compatibility.  
Use avconv instead (see Changelog for the list of incompatible changes).
```

A small improvement in my opinion, but I feel as if it is not clear enough.

#### Which one do I use?

Nobody can tell you which one to use. The main difference for users is that FFmpeg merges many commits from libav, but it's not so reciprocal since libav seems to pretend that FFmpeg does not exist and only occasionally cherry-picks from FFmpeg.

To the casual user, there should not be huge differences. To get FFmpeg you can follow a [compile guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) or see the download links for executables on the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page.

For more info see [The FFmpeg/Libav situation](http://blog.pkh.me/p/13-the-ffmpeg-libav-situation.html).

Comment: It's beyond a badly worded message, it's flat out wrong. FFmpeg hasn't stopped development at all, in fact FFmpeg has a far larger community than LibAV... the Ubuntu maintainers made that message to trick users into using LibAV out of the mistaken belief that FFmpeg was dead. it's 100% pure malice.

Comment: avconv doesn't even support LADSPA

Comment: @MarcusJ ...technically it was the debian maintainers. But yes, I agree; it's deceitful.

Answer (score 40):

**Update (early 2016)**

- The odds stay in favor of ffmpeg. Most distros have switched back/are switching back to ffmpeg ([Gentoo](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.gentoo.devel/95339/focus=95585), [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/Debate/libav-provider/ffmpeg))
- One practical advantage of ffmpeg is the broad availibility of binaries for many platforms. Googling for static libs/dynamic libs/binaries yields good results for linux,mac,windows,ios and android for ffmpeg, while I could only  find linux and windows builds for libav. This could be an important point if you have little experience with C/makefiles.

**The current situation (mid 2015)**

It appears to be better to stick with FFmpeg. The whole situation is rather messy and ugly. I just started reading up on the fork a few days ago. Ignoring all the drama, here are what appear to be facts:

- FFmpeg incorporates change sets from libav, while libav is reluctant to do so (see [debian debate](https://wiki.debian.org/Debate/libav-provider/ffmpeg#Upstream_Contributors))
- Chrome uses ffmpeg, and google has put serious effort into making it secure. libav is also incorporating those changes, but at a slower pace ([google blog post](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.at/2014/01/ffmpeg-and-thousand-fixes.html))
- FFmpeg attempts to keep as many codecs as possible, while libav dropped some ([libav mailing list](https://lists.libav.org/pipermail/libav-devel/2012-October/036799.html), [post from a libav dev](http://codecs.multimedia.cx/?p=370))
- The FFmpeg community is larger than libav, and the most dedicated developer (michael niedermayer) stuck with FFmpeg ([commit stats](http://lucy.pkh.me/ffstats/authors.html#cumulated_added_lines_of_code_per_author))
- The ubuntu/debian maintainers for FFmpeg were part of the libav fork. they added deprecation messages to some command line tools, hinting that ffmpeg is deprecated. this caused a lot of confusion. both [debian](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/11/ffmpeg-returns-to-official-ubuntu.html) and [ubuntu](https://lwn.net/Articles/650495/) are switching back to ffmpeg.

Comment: I happened to Google Michael Niedermayer and ended up with [this post](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2015-July/176489.html), in which he resigns.

Comment: Niedermayer was __the reason__ for the fork. That said, he changed a lot.

Answer (score 9):

When you go [here](http://ffmpeg.org) you'll see that the most recent update is September 2012 (a few months ago).

It looks like [this](http://code.google.com/p/winff/issues/detail?id=147) says it's just specific to Ubuntu and Debian at this time.

> Some time ago ffmpeg split into two forks under the name of ffmpeg and
>   libav.
>
> Debian is following the libav fork in it's distribution and in an
>   upcoming upload the binary /usr/bin/ffmpeg will be replaced by
>   /usr/bin/avconv.
>
> As far as I know it is not necessary to switch immediately, but Winff
>   should be upgraded to allow for either binary (from the Debian
>   perspective, with a preference for avconv). I know you can set the
>   location of the binary in the preferences, but I think that with the
>   location set, Winff should be able to find the proper binary.
>
> I think in the future also Windows and other distributions might be
>   hit by this issue.

To answer your question about whether or not it's exactly the same:

> I have implemented the checks for the correct binary in my local
>   checkout, but reading up [1](http://ffmpeg.org), I see that there are some
>   inconsistencies between avconv and ffmpeg. That issue is larger,
>   because the preset file will need adjustment and especially the way we
>   create the command line will have to change. The options that operate
>   on the input file need to go BEFORE the input file "-i".

Please note, this may be specific to the Windows version.  This was posted regarding the Linux version:

> FFmpeg audio/video conversion tool is now known as AVConv (a better
>   name in my opinion). So "ffmpeg" command line tool is obsolete and
>   "avconv" should be used. As far as I noticed all parameters remained
>   the same, but further investigations should be made. Some
>   modifications need to be done in CIS.
>
> Tasks:
>
> Install AVConv on the machine(s) that run CIS. Usually avconv should
>   appear be updating ffmpeg (that worked on Ubuntu; not tested for
>   Debian). Replace "ffmpeg" with "avconv" in cis/api/ffmpeg.py, class
>   FFmpegTranscoder, field prog_bin, which represents the conversion tool
>   executable. Refactor file names, class names, method names, variable
>   names etc. that contain "FFmpeg" or "ffmpeg" such that they contain
>   AVConv. An IDE like Eclipse could do this automatically. Test! If
>   problems are noticed, debug!