# Can I expedite VLC stream to make files faster?

Tags: video, streaming, vlc-media-player, video-streaming

I want to split a long 50 minute video file into two 25 minute parts. I finally found out how to stream one video file into another video file via the command line thanks to http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch03.html and http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch04.html docs.

Here is the terminal command I used to achieve this:

```
vlc original_video.mp4 --start-time 0 --stop-time 1500 --sout "#standard{access=file,mux=ts,dst=/home/max/Desktop/video_A.mp4}"
```

The only problem is that it seems as though VLC is just sitting there streaming the `original_video.mp4` into `video-A.mp4`. I stopped it after 5 minutes and saw that `video_A.mp4` was only 5 minutes long.

**Is there a way to exedite this process?**

Comment: Are you open to options other than VLC? I know that ffmpeg can do what you're trying to do (because I've done it myself), and it should even be lossless.

Comment: Sure I am open to it. I just installed ffmpeg on Ubuntu although when I try to use it in Terminal it tells me to use `avconv` instead. Can you tell me how to split my big video file?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ffmpeg`'s [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) (scroll down a bit on that link for some examples). Basically:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -f segment -segment_times 1500 output%02d.mp4
```

This will produce two files, 'output01.mp4' and 'output02.mp4'. If you were to use `output%03d.mp4`, you would instead get 'output001.mp4' and 'output002.mp4'.

`-segment_times` calls for a comma-separated list of split-points, measured in seconds. As you only want to split once, at 25 minutes, just use 1500 (=25*60). Note that `-segment_time` (without the 's') is a completely separate option - you'd use that if you wanted to split the file every five seconds (for example), without putting in a big list of every specific time.

You may find that you need to use `-reset_timestamps 1` for the files to play correctly:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -f segment -segment_times 1500 -reset_timestamps 1 output%02d.mp4
```

There are a lot more options on the documentation page. This should be pretty quick, and lossless (so you'll get identical video with no extra video artefacts). However, it won't be 100% accurate, since ffmpeg needs to split on a [key frame](https://superuser.com/questions/587557/ffmpeg-add-keyframes-without-reencoding/587567#587567), which can't be guaranteed without re-encoding.

*If* you need accurate splitting, the documentation recommends re-encoding and using the `-force_key_frames` and `-segment_time_delta` options to ensure that there will be [I-frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-frame) on the times that the segment muxer will attempt to split on (see also the [libx264](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) and [AAC](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) encoding guides on the [ffmpeg wiki](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki)):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 3 \
-force_key_frames 1500 -f segment -segment_times 1500 -segment_time_delta 0.05 output%02d.mp4
```

The version of ffmpeg in most Linux repositories is going to be quite old, and in the case of Debian and Ubuntu et al the situation is even worse: they do not provide ffmpeg, but rather the fork, [avconv, from the libav team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv/9477756#9477756) (see also [LordNeckbeard's answer here](https://superuser.com/a/507473/180990)). AVconv is a perfectly fine tool on its own, but I can't guarantee that the ffmpeg syntax will work with it 100% of the time, especially with 'advanced' stuff like this.

I would recommend either [grabbing a static build from the ffmpeg Downloads page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) or [compiling it yourself](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CompilationGuide). The main benefit of compiling it yourself is that you can get access to `libfdk_aac`, the best AAC audio encoder that ffmpeg can use - which cannot be legally distributed in a compiled ffmpeg binary, due to licensing conflicts (fdk_aac uses a custom copyleft license, which isn't quite compatible with ffmpeg's GPL).

Comment: Hmm thanks but I get an error `Unrecognized option 'segment_times'` when I try `ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -c copy -f segment -segment_times 1500 output%02d.mp4` and when I change it to `-segment_time` I get this error `Output file #0 does not contain any stream`