# How to split and join without transcoding AVC/MPEG-TS video files in Windows with ffmpeg?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video-editing, mpeg

I am looking also for a Linux solution (in [a separate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232711/32012))

I have two recorded video files with the extension `.ts`. I need to remove some part of the first, split the second, and then merge the first file with the first (split) part of the second file.

They both have the same characteristics:

```
Format                                   : MPEG-TS
File size                                : 3.16 GiB
Duration                                 : 1h 39mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 4 527 Kbps

Video
ID                                       : 720 (0x2D0)
Menu ID                                  : 6181 (0x1825)
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : 27
Duration                                 : 1h 39mn
Width                                    : 1 440 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : MBAFF
```

They also contain multiple audio tracks and subtitles.

I want to process them without transcoding the files, at least be able to remove the beginning etc.

## `FFMPEG`:

`ffmpeg -i source.mts` gives:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'source1.mts':
      Duration: 01:40:00.76, start: 2995.511878, bitrate: 4526 kb/s
      Program 6181
        Stream #0:0[0x46](fra,fra): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
        Stream #0:1[0x2d0]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
        Stream #0:2[0x2da](fra): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 73 kb/s
        Stream #0:3[0x2db](qaa): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 67 kb/s
        Stream #0:4[0x2dc](deu): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 49 kb/s
        Stream #0:5[0x2dd](qad): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 57 kb/s
```

I think it is very well doable with `ffmpeg`, which is also cross-platform, as a command that I found [here](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-software-cut-split-or-merge-video-files.htm#comment-115665)  to remove a part of one file.

```
ffmpeg -i InputFile -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:12:34.567 -t 00:34:56.789 OutputFile
```

works, excepting the fact that the input has four audio tracks and in this way only the first (`Stream #0:2[0x2da](fra)`) audio is taken. What I want is: either all audio, either the third (`Stream #0:3[0x2db](qaa)`). How to adjust?

`ffmpeg` should therefore work to:

**1. Cut off the beginning of the first file (remove first 2 minutes out of 1h40 min file)**

**2. Split a second (1 hour) file in two parts (after 3.05 minutes)**

**3. Join (append) to the end of the first file the 3.05 min part obtained from splitting the second file.**

---

What I have tried:

Openshot: cannot process without transcoding.

Avidemux (Linux): when trying to save it says *"This is not MPEG compatible - You cannot use the Copy codec."*

Avidemux in Windows: audio is out of sync.

Comment: All I would add is that given the change in scope of the question[s], I would be wary about leaving your unix.SE question open, as it may be seen as cross-posting, which is frowned on. Its up to you to decide if both need to remain open, and I am making no judgement myself but I suspect others might view it as such.

Comment: @bertieb - Although common answers may be provided, my U&L question now stands as a different one, as it asks for a general Linux solution, while this one asks for a FFMPEG solution in Windows. - I have indeed created an answer for Linux based on your answer here, and posted here a simplified version of your answer, adding also a possible GUI solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How do I split and join files using `ffmpeg` while retaining all audio tracks?

As you have discovered, a bitstream copy will select only **one** (audio) track, as per the [stream specification documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection):

> By default, `ffmpeg` includes only one stream of each type (video, audio, subtitle) present in the input files and adds them to each output file. It picks the "best" of each based upon the following criteria: for video, it is the stream with the highest resolution, for audio, it is the stream with the most channels, for subtitles, it is the first subtitle stream. In the case where several streams of the same type rate equally, the stream with the lowest index is chosen.

To select *all* audio tracks:

```
ffmpeg -i InputFile.ts-c copy -ss 00:12:34.567 -t 00:34:56.789 -map 0:v -map 0:a FirstFile.ts
```

To select the *third* audio track:

```
ffmpeg -i InputFile.ts -c copy -ss 00:12:34.567 -t 00:34:56.789 -map 0:v -map 0:a:2 FirstFile.ts
```

You can read more about and see other examples of stream selection in the [advanced options](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) section of the `ffmpeg` documentation.

I would also combine `-vcodec copy -acodec copy` from your original command into `-c copy` as above for compactness of expression.

## Split:

So, combining those with what you want to achieve in the two files in terms of splitting for later re-joining:

```
ffmpeg -i InputOne.ts -ss 00:02:00.0 -c copy -map 0:v -map 0:a OutputOne.ts
ffmpeg -i InputTwo.ts -c copy -t 00:03:05.0 -map 0:v -map 0:a OutputTwo.ts
```

will give you:

- **`OutputOne.ts`**, which is everything *after* the first two minutes of the first input file
- **`OutputTwo.ts`**, which is the *first* 3 minutes and 5 seconds of the second input file

## Join:

`ffmpeg` supports concatenation of files without re-encoding, [described extensively in its concatenation documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

Create your listing of files to be joined (eg `join.txt`):

```
file '/path/to/files/OutputOne.ts'
file '/path/to/files/OutputTwo.ts'
```

Then your `ffmpeg` command can use the `concat demuxer`:

```
 ffmpeg -f concat -i join.txt -c copy FinalOutput.ts
```

Since you are working with `mpeg` transport streams (`.ts`), you *should* be able to use the concat **protocol** as well:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:OutputOne.ts|OutputTwo.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

Per the example on the concat page linked above. I'll leave that up to you to experiment with.

Comment: I forgot to include the video `-map`ping, thanks for the reminder. I have updated the question on how to join (concatenate) video files together as per your edit.

Comment: My edit includes a section on joining files. I'm still not sure what you mean by the 'split' but I'm glad you have a command that works :)

Comment: How many outputs do you want? One, the final joined file? Or do you need *both* parts of the split on the second file kept?

Comment: To keep *all* streams (video, audio, subtitles), replace all `-map`s with the single: `-map 0`

Comment: please edit the `join.txt` content: the path to files has to be in reversed comas to work. but none of the solutions for joining allows keeping all audio, as only default/first is selected

Comment: Good catch, I could swear I had those in in a previous revision. Relative paths will also work.

Comment: is there a way to join the files with all audio?  they are lost except the default one when joining. or i'll select at a previous stage the one preferred and use that in both files to be joined

Comment: If the `concat`demuxer *also* only grabs the 'best' track ( would expect it to work differently, but then this is `ffmpeg`...), I would include the `-map 0` in that step as well.

Comment: interesting, a comment under [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/370190/47206) saying `-ss` should be used before  `-i`, while `-t`  should be after `-i`. Also: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking and http://askubuntu.com/a/547995/47206

Comment: The positioning of `ffmpeg` commands is very important. `-ss` can be used either before or after `-i` for slightly different methods of achieving the same thing (frame-accurate seeking). You can alternatively use `-to` if you prefer to specify an end time, rather than a duration (`-t`).

Comment: replacing `ffmpeg` with `avconv` works ok I guess in Linux. Is it available for Windows too?

Comment: `ffmpeg` is available for Windows systems via [Zeranoe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), yes. I'd rather not get into `ffmpeg` vs `avconv`, but see http://superuser.com/questions/507386/why-would-i-choose-libav-over-ffmpeg-or-is-there-even-a-difference and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/what-are-the-differences-and-similarities-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv/9477756#9477756

Comment: After "To select all audio tracks:", change the command by adding a space after `InputFile.ts`

Answer (score 4):

As a simplified answer based on the main one:

To keep data after a start point (up to the end):

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -c copy -ss START_TIME -map 0 OUTPUT
```

To keep data between two time points:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -c copy -ss START_TIME -to END_TIME -map 0 OUTPUT
```

To keep data of a certain duration after a certain point:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -c copy -ss START_TIME -t DURATION_TIME -map 0 OUTPUT
```

To keep data of a certain duration after beginning:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -c copy -t DURATION_TIME -map 0 OUTPUT
```

To keep data from beginning up to a time point:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -c copy -to TIME_POINT -map 0 OUTPUT
```

**TIME may be a number in seconds, or in hh:mm:ss[.xxx]**

---

To join files, create a file called `join.txt` with the content

```
file 'path-to-INPUT1'
file 'path-to-INPUT2'
file...etc
```

then

```
 ffmpeg -f concat -i join.txt OUTPUT
```

Or:

To join mpeg files (including transport files)

```
 ffmpeg -i "concat:INPUT-1|INPUT-2" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc OUTPUT
```

---

As a GUI solution, I have tried Avidemux but with bad results. When searching a Linux solution I have found this comment [here](https://kdenlive.org/comment/14163#comment-14163) pointing to **Avidemux nightly**:

*"You can try Avidemux, but not the stable one. You should try the win32 version (yes, for windows) with "Wine". It supports H.264 and you must use the double arrow to find out the keyframes because you can[not] cut everywhere (due to the "long gop" thing...). But, as every software like this, you can do JUST CUTS otherwise it will render (in case of transitions, effects, ectc.).
http://avidemux.org/nightly/win32/"*

I have tested that in Linux/Wine but it should work in Windows too.

[image]

To join files, use *File-Open* to add first file, and then *File-Append* for the rest.

To save: *File - Save.*